# Get error in php snmpget

Tags: php, snmp

I need to get system up time in my project. I got a solution from php.net. But when I use this code I got this error "Warning: snmpget(): Invalid object identifier: system.sysUpTime.0".

My code is

```
$sysuptime[0] = snmpget('192.168.10.24', 'public', "system.sysUpTime.0");
$sysuptime[1] = eregi_replace("Timeticks:","",$sysuptime[0]);
echo 'System Uptime: Timeticks -'.$sysuptime[1].'<br>';
```

Help me plz.

Comment: `eregi_replace` This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. Use `preg_replace`

Comment: @dude, may be have the version issue, http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
"PHP 5.3.0, 5.3.1 and 5.3.2 do not have SNMP support. SNMP support has restored in PHP 5.3.3."

Comment: @SAM My php version is 5.4.9.Thanks.

Comment: @ZawMyoHtet, hey, add a upvote atleast

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error.
I realized that the problem could be in many places, so the first thing I did was I thought, maybe the function does not recognize the parameters it has been passed, or it cannot resolve it. So I passed a normal snmp OID to it and it just gave me this answer:
*Warning: snmpget(): No response from 127.0.0.1*
This is just due to that my pc does not have any snmp agent software to process the request for sysContact OID:
    $syscontact = snmpget("127.0.0.1", "public", "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5");

I posted this to point you in a direction to find the problem. You have to determine why php cannot process the *system.sysUpTime.0*, this could be to do with php not being able to read its default MIB files.

Comment: I am currently in the process of setting up and testin my php snmp installation.

Comment: Great. After playing around. I found this: You have to correctly set your Windows Environment Variables for the PHP to use the snmp MIBs. That is how php will be able to understand the 'dot' notation you pass as parameter. (IF YOU ARE RUNNING WINDOWS TO SAY).

Comment: Do you have any hint, where to put MIB files on Windows? Maybe: C:\Program Files\Net-SNMP\share\snmp\mibs? @Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet :\

In Windows, I had the environment variable MIBDIRS set up, and it still wasn't working.
I had to add the MIBDIRS to the registry under the NetSNMP Key in HKLM
This was for Windows/IIS/Php

Other notes, with the EnvVar setup, using the snmpwalk.exe and a Named OID worked, but using a Named OID in php wasn't until I added the registry value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31835361)